# Is it a security risk to use the names of SQL parameters client-side?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, security, parameters

I have a web method that runs a given SQL procedure and returns the result as a serialised table. It could use one of a number of procedures, and each one requires different parameters:

- Proc1 requires `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`
- Proc2 requires `@StartDate`, `@EndDate` and `@ResourceType`
- Proc3 requires `@StartDate`, `@EndDate` and `@ClientName`
- Proc4 requires `@StartDate`, `@User`, `@ResourceType` and `@RowsToReturn`

If the parameters are passed as an array from the client to the web method, the web method needs to know which value corresponds to which parameter. That means the names need to be associated with the values before they are passed, and that means the names need to be paired with the values in the client JavaScript, making them visible to the user.

My question is: **does revealing the parameter names in this way increase the system's susceptibility to intrusion?  Or are they already revealed to the user in some other way?**

For example (using jQuery):

```
$.get(
    "Service.svc/GetData",
    JSON.stringify({
        query: "Proc2",
        params: [
            { name: "@StartDate", val: "01-JAN-2019" },
            { name: "@EndDate", val: "31-JAN-2019" },
            { name: "@ResourceType", val: 12 }
           ]
        }),
    function() { console.log(r.d); },
    "json"
    )
```

Comment: You may receive better questions to this answer on [InfoSec.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/).